# R: using felm to instrument two variables with two different instrument variables

Tags: r, regression

O have two question regarding using felm for instrumneting two variables with two different instrumental variables

This is my original regression:

OLS<-felm(wob ~ prc_a + prc_b + prc_c + prc_d + size + ROA + lev |YEAR+Ind|0|0, data=final)

prc_a and prc_b are endogenous and need to be instrumented

I want to instrument prc_a with alpha and prc_b with beta

Questions:

1. shall I run it all at once?
   if so, is this the right code:

OLS_IV <-felm(wob ~ prc_c + prc_d + size + ROA + lev |YEAR+Ind|(prc_a + prc_b ~  alpha + beta)|0, data=final)

or separately:

OLS_IV1<-felm(wob ~ prc_b + prc_c + prc_d + size + ROA + lev |YEAR+Ind|(prc_a  ~  alpha)|0, data=final)
OLS_IV2<-felm(wob ~ prc_a + prc_c + prc_d + size + ROA + lev |YEAR+Ind|(prc_b  ~  beta)|0, data=final)

2. when I run
   OLS<-felm(wob ~ prc_a + prc_b + prc_c + prc_d + size + ROA + lev |YEAR+Ind|0|0, data=final)
   and
   OLS_IV1<-felm(wob ~ prc_b + prc_c + prc_d + size + ROA + lev |YEAR+Ind|(prc_a  ~  alpha)|0, data=final),

coefficient of the instrumented variable is very much different than in the original OLS

But when I run IV keeping the original variable prc_a as well as instrumenting it later in the code:
OLS_alt<-felm(wob ~ prc_a + prc_b + prc_c + prc_d + size + ROA + lev |YEAR+Ind|(prc_a  ~  alpha)|0, data=final)

then the magnitudes match.

Which approach is correct?